# Spark SQL broadcast hint intermediate tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem using Broadcast hints (maybe is some lack of SQL knowledge).

I have a query like

```
SELECT * /* broadcast(a) */
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b
ON ....
INNER JOIN c
on ....
```

I would like to do

```
SELECT * /* broadcast(a) */
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b 
ON ....
INNER JOIN c /* broadcast(AjoinedwithB) */
on ....
```

I mean, I want to force broadcast join (I would prefer to avoid changing spark parameters to force it everywhere), but I don't know how to refer to the table named `AjoinedwithB`

Of course I can split the SQL, work with DF API and such... but I would like to do it in a single SQL Query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either subquery

```sql
SELECT /*+ broadcast(a_b) */ *
FROM 
    (SELECT /*+ broadcast(a) */ * FROM a JOIN b ON ...) AS a_b 
    JOIN c ON ...
```

or CTE:

```sql
WITH a_b AS (SELECT /*+ broadcast(a) */ * FROM a JOIN b ON ...)
SELECT /*+ broadcast(a_b) */ * FROM a_b JOIN c ON ...
```

Comment: Thanks (I thought I had written this post already :S), wanted to do something a little more transparent (I knew subquery already), but i didn't know about CTE, and I guess there's not other option :)